# "Not an answer" flag declined for eventually deleted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging, specific-answer

I see [this declined flag](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11278?showDeclined=true) in my flag history. This is related to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49011/why-are-the-syria-and-iraq-wars-viewed-differently-among-democrats/49015#49015) which got deleted (not sure if that related to my flag or not).

That answer did not look like a proper answer, but a decent comment instead case included in the flag text (not an answer but a comment).

Isn't flagging with Not An Answer the appropriate way to get a comment-like answer removed or converted to a comment?

Comment: Weirdly that link 404s for me, even though it works correctly if I input my User ID. You definitely flagged Not An Answer then? If so I'd have said that was entirely appropriate. My only guess would be an accidental mis-flagging for another reason.

Comment: @DanScally Flags are private, so you can only view your own flag history. My guess as to what happened: The answer is low quality and on the border to being a comment, not an answer. As it's a close call, the mod reviewing the flag didn't want to use their mod powers to delete it but instead let the community handle it. That's why the flag was declined. The community then decided to delete the answer, but the "declined" status of flags doesn't change retroactively.

Comment: Personally, I would have downvoted the answer, might have voted to delete it, but wouldn't have flagged it. I would use the "not an answer" flag for answers which are clearly comments on *other* answers or comments asking for clarification on the question, or something else which isn't even close to attempting to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I came across it in the low-quality queue. I voted to delete it because it adds no supporting evidence to show why it shapes Democrats' views (which is the subject of the question).

I don't think this would have been a good comment either. The reason for that is that it lacks any evidence or reasoning why this is relevant to the question. If this had been a comment, it could not be down voted, only up voted, so it may have gathered 4 up votes as the answer did.

Instead, the appropriate thing would be to have more elaboration and evidence to support the answer. Reasonably, under whose command US involvement started can be argued to shape Democrats' views. For example, because of the way it's covered in one's filter bubble or because of the reasons the US entered into the conflict in the first place aligning with party affiliation. That reasoning is the most important part of a post, but it lacks any such reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

I declined the flags because the answer did, indeed, appear to be an answer to the question that was asked.

It was deleted by vote by 4 high-rep users.  Moderators aren't the only way an answer can be deleted.